# With FUSE how can I get read requests that don't happen in 4096 sized chunks?

Tags: fuse

FUSE seems to buffer or cache read requests so that they appear in 4096 (probably the system page size) sized chunks. However, I'm faking an IPC data structure like a pipe or a message queue so I need to get the raw request and size. How can I get the real size requested by a read request in FUSE?

Answer (score 1):

The statfs function lets you set the minimum block size for reads with
the f_bsize structure member.

```
static int my_statfs(char const * path, struct statvfs *buf)
{
    void *my_data = fuse_get_context()->private_data;

    // Get data

    secure_zero(buf, sizeof *buf);

    /* Must be 1 so that reads and writes aren't broken up into
     * larger chunks.*/
    buf->f_bsize = 1U;
    buf->f_frsize = 0U;    /* ignored */
    buf->f_blocks = 0U;
    buf->f_bfree = 0U;
    buf->f_bavail = 0U;

    buf->f_files = MY_INODES_MAX;
    buf->f_ffree = inodes;

    buf->f_favail = 0U;    /* ignored */

    buf->f_fsid = 0U;    /* ignored */
    buf->f_flag = 0U; /* ignored */
    buf->f_namemax = MY_PATH_MAX;

    return 0;
}
```